# Why "doOnError" not working until "err->{}" is not passed to "subscribe()" method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a following transformation function:

```
private MutableLiveData<ApiError> apiError = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MutableLiveData<ApiProgress> apiProgress = new MutableLiveData<>();
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

// Emit "progress's start" on subscribe and "progress's end" on after success or error.
// Add this to the observable action sequence with ".compose(baseTransformer())" before subscribe.
<T> SingleTransformer<T, T> baseTransformer() {
    return upstream -> upstream
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
                apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.start());
            })
            .doFinally(() -> apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.stop()))
            .doOnError(err -> {
                apiError.setValue(ApiError.create(err));
            });
}
```

and I am using this function here:

```
authRepository.login(userName, password)
            .compose(baseTransformer())
            .subscribe(login -> {
                loginData.setValue(login);
            });
```

**Problem:** My application crashes when trying to login.
**Solution**

```
authRepository.login(userName, password)
            .compose(baseTransformer())
            .subscribe(login -> {
                loginData.setValue(login);
            }, err -> {});
```

I don't know why it fixes the problem as "doOnError" should not be dependent on this lambda("err -> {}") to catch the error.

Please suggest any alternative.

Comment: `doOnError` lets you peek into the error channel but is does not consume the error. You still need an `onError` callback or `onErrorX` operator to really handle the error.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the example here: https://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-error-handling

Comment: 3.1 is wrong...

Comment: 3.1 is correct. It alters external state but the testObserver still receives the error.

Comment: But that person has not handled error in `subscribe` method so I think the `doOnError` will never get a call. Am I right ?

Comment: The testObserver receives and consumes the error, so it is not thrown as unhandled exception. Your first example ignores the error in the subscribe.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what should be the implementation of `TestObserver` there. Could you please give me an example.

Comment: It's a class provided by RxJava: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/TestObserver.html

Comment: Understood. TestObserver should implement `BiConsumer<T, Throwable>`. Thank you for all your help.